# Can not see commit in bitbucket repository. Commit has been successful

Tags: git, bitbucket, egit

I have done 2 commits on 07.10.2014 on bitbucket using Egit plugin in eclipse. But I do not see them on list of commits neither can anyone else from my team see these commits. Commits were successful. When I try to open a file in Team sync , I see a different commit file number which is not available on bit bitbuckt at all. Can someone from bitbucket support team help with this issue?

Comment: Have you ever pushed your commits?

Comment: Yes , I have. I use Commit & Push always.

Comment: and what does `git status` say?

Comment: How do you check git status? After the commit it displayed message that commit was successful but when I refresh the page with list of commits in bitbucket it does not show up.

Comment: mh I'm not familiar with egit. `git status` is a terminal command. See http://githowto.com/checking_status

Comment: A screenshot of the History view in Eclipse would help, as well as the `.git/config` of your repository.

Comment: Looks like I have detached HEAD , how do I resolve this issue? I am using Egit plugin for eclips.

Comment: Seems like bitbucket didn't yet resolve the issue. I also saw such problem today and sometimes lost to see the previous commit until I push the next one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Looks like I have detached HEAD , how do I resolve this issue? I am using Egit plugin for eclipse

I assume you want to change your local branch e.g. `master` to point to that commit? If so, this is how to do it:

1. Create a branch on the current commit
2. Switch to the `master` branch (also called checkout)
3. Do Team > Reset... and select the branch you previously created

Now master points to that commit and you can remove the branch you created in the first step.

Comment: Thanks , AS of now I am pointing to new repository which had my  commits and it is pushing commits and showing them on bitbucket. So I am fine for now. But I am not sure how all the commits moved to different repository.

Answer (score 0):

Recently experienced this issue and I resolved it by using:

git status in the terminal which showed that my local git branch was ahead of my remote branch by 8 commits:

[image]

running **git Push** resolved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I had a case where I haven't committed the changes and I kept on pushing it to the remote branch, was a very silly mistake but after finding out why this was happening I simply wrote

git commit -m "Commit message goes here";

then I pushed the changes to the origin branch, finally refreshed the bitbucket page and I can see those changes.